Trying to install windows 10 without a monitor
I'm trying to install windows 10 on a laptop with a broken screen. Normally I just have it plugged into a monitor via a HDMI cable, but while installing windows 10, it absolutely refuses to display on that monitor after the first restart. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I don't have much money either so "buying a new computer" isn't really an option. Thanks in advance!

What's a compatible dock? I'm not sure I've heard that before

Don't worry about that. A dock will be the same as any external HDMI or other. Installation can be problem indeed. Have you tried Win+P? I never did it during an installation but it might work. Other possibility is the laptop's own monitor toggle key/key combo, if applicable.

What other video ports are available, if any?  BTW, if all else fails, try running Windows from USB (WinToUsb), or try another OS that runs better from USB, or is easier to install without monitor, such as Linux.
